# Model number of iPhone 4S Officially Unlocked

Tags: iphone

Can someone please tell me the model number (something like MC920LL) of their Officially unlocked iPhone 4S 16GB White, that Apple started selling since Nov 11.

There are various other contract-free phones available but they are not truly unlocked since there is a risk of being locked in the future maybe.

So if anyone has bought the OFFICIALLY unlocked white or black iPhone 4S from apple directly, can you PLEASE share the model number?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some details concerning these unlocked models which,ay be locked after all?

Comment: Since this info is easily available using Apple's website or Google, I'm closing this question as [General Reference](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/). Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The model number doesn't have anything to do with whether the phone is locked or not. The model number is tied to the unit's hardware components. All current black and white iPhone 4S' have the model number: **A1387**

The only time you'll see a different model number during the same production line is when Apple makes a hardware change (such as the iPhone 4 GSM and CDMA versions, or the 3GS "old" and "new" bootroms).

More details found [over at Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3939).

Comment: Not that model nnumber. Search for MC920LL/A and you'll see.

Comment: @Nimbuz The part number (located on the box and listed under Settings > General > About) vary greatly from carrier to country. It's a complex system that truly only Apple knows. You question will likely remain unanswered as for any given area, there could be dozens of part numbers. You can read more here: http://technolo.co/20100826/identifying-a-factory-unlocked-iphone-4/ My iPhone 4S has the part number 922. My friend's is 918. All are 16GB 4Ses.

Comment: Yes, thats why I want to know from someone who already has the officially unlocked phone purchased from US.

Comment: @Nimbuz Like I said. There are likely dozens of different part numbers floating around. AT&T is no longer the only carrier. Even if someone posted their part number, thats just one of the many available. Do you understand that? One single part number would be of little value if you're only using it as a comparison. You'd need them all.